# Parse abbreviated numbers in Ruby

Tags: ruby

What's the best way in Ruby to turn human-readable abbreviated numbers into actual integers?

Examples:

```
"1.2M" => 1200000
"477k" => 477000
```

Comment: If you can't find a lib to do this -- you probably will -- how many abbreviations are there? If there are less than 20, you could code it in a few minutes, right?

Comment: Should `k` indicate `1000` or `1024`? If the former, do you need to support `ki` for `1024`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
module SIValue
  # http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_prefix
  PREFIX_MAGNITUDES = {
    'Y' =>  24, 'Z' =>  21, 'E' =>  18, 'P' =>  15, 'T'  =>  12,
    'G' =>   9, 'M' =>   6, 'k' =>   3, 'h' =>   2, 'da' =>   1,
    'd' =>  -1, 'c' =>  -2, 'm' =>  -3, 'μ' =>  -6, 'n'  =>  -9,
    'p' => -12, 'f' => -15, 'a' => -18, 'z' => -21, 'y'  => -24
  }
  def self.from( str )
    _, num, prefix = str.match(/^([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?)(#{PREFIX_MAGNITUDES.keys.join('|')})?/o).to_a
    if num
      prefix ? num.to_f * 10**PREFIX_MAGNITUDES[prefix] : num.to_f
    else
      0.0
    end
  end
end

%w[ 1k +3.3m +3.3M 123.123da 0.31h 0.31μ cats ].each do |s|
  p [s,SIValue.from(s) ]
end
#=> ["1k", 1000.0]
#=> ["+3.3m", 0.0033]
#=> ["+3.3M", 3300000.0]
#=> ["123.123da", 1231.23]
#=> ["0.31h", 31.0]
#=> ["0.31μ", 3.1e-07]
#=> ["cats", 0.0]
```

Comment: That looks pretty good though I'd use strings rather than symbols for the keys to avoid having to convert. I'd also recommend not using the _ variable. It's such a Perlism; Shun the Perlism.

Comment: Heh, was just in the middle of converting to use strings :) Do you have a better way to ignore the first match conveniently?

Comment: "Do you have a better way to ignore the first match conveniently?", sure! Slice the result to skip the unbeliever... err, undesired value: `[1..-1]` or `[1,2]`

Comment: @Greg Thanks; not sure I consider that an improvement, but it does avoid the underscore.

Comment: In Perl you could replace `_` with `undef`, but it won't work in Ruby.

Comment: @Phrogz Use the splat operator. *ignore, num, prefix = str .match etc.

Comment: @steenslag I don't see how that's an improvement. We know that it is exactly one value that we wish to avoid. You might argue that `ignore` is a better name than `_` to indicate that a variable is undesired; I would argue the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

```
def scale s
  a = s.downcase.split /(?=[a-z])/
  Integer(a.first.to_f * Hash.new(1).merge('k' => 1024, 'm' => 1024 * 1024)[a[1]] + 0.5)
end

 # you may want to extend the hash with more suffix types
```